# Locale.getLanguage() equalize to String

Tags: java, android, arrays, locale

I'm trying to make an android app with multiple languages. I have a string array. What i am trying to do is make this array for multiple languages. For example; I have an array in English like "Mercury, Venus, Earth, Mars". Also i have an array in Turkish like "Merkür, Venüs, Dünya, Mars". I'm learning device's main language with "Locale" property and i can show that language. But what i want to do is show the language array depends on the device's main language.

As i said, i have two array. I tried to learn device's language and equlize the string array. But i can't equlize them because of .equals parameter. It didn't work.

```
String[] TurkishPlanetNames ={"Merkür", "Venüs", "Dünya", "Mars", "Jüpiter", "Satürn", "Uranüs", "Neptün"};

String[] PlanetNames ={"Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars", "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Neptune"};
```

---

```
Locale locale = ConfigurationCompat.getLocales(Resources.getSystem().getConfiguration()).get(0);

if (locale.getLanguage().equals("en-US")){

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "It worked!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "It didn't work!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

So, how can i equalize the device's language and a string like "en-US". .equals - .compareTo - .contentEquals - .matches are doesn't work.

Comment: Now this is **not** how Android localization works. You should have the localized arrays, with the *same name*, in different folders. The system would then automatically pick the localized array for you based on the system language.

Comment: I know. I'm already trying to do that. if(device language is en){show this language array} else if(device language is tr){then show this language array}. And it worked

Comment: You don't have to mess with it **programmatically**. **Android does it for you**, if you use the proper resource files. Without using a single `if`

Comment: But, i'm using a listview. how can i automatically translate this depends device's language

Comment: You really need to read the official documentation.

Comment: This is the documentation that @Fantômas mentions, that could provide an alternative (best approach) to what you're doing right now: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization

Comment: I'm already using that. But, i'm using a listview. how can i translate listview automatically in java classes. I'm just trying to say that. On the other hand, i don't have any problem for now. It's not a big application. I solve the problem from the long way. but it's working

Comment: Again, arrays are **automatically translated**. No matter whether you use them to populate a ListView, a Spinner or anything. You don't have to do that manually. It's wasted effort, since the system does it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`locale.getLanguage();` would return just "en" no matter what version of English your device uses (British/American).

The following call will return the string in the format you're trying to use in your `.equals();`

```
Locale.getDefault().toString(); //e.g. returns "en_US"
```

but make sure you use the underscore instead of the hyphen.

Alternatively, use the method you're currently using as follows:

```
if (locale.getLanguage().equals(new Locale("en").getLanguage())) {
    //...
}
```

([source](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Locale.html#getDisplayLanguage(java.util.Locale)))